# How do I retrieve the last 10 inserts on a Cassandra table partitioned by timestamp?

Tags: cassandra, cql

I've seen a few questions of a similar problem already but none of them seem to apply to my particular case.

I have this table which contains the timestamp as primary key and a random value:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS rand_keyspace.rands (
timestamp bigint,
randnumber float,
PRIMARY KEY (timestamp));
```

I would like to retrieve the last 10 inserted rows.

```
SELECT * FROM rand_keyspace.rands ORDER BY timestamp DESC LIMIT 10;
```

and I'm getting the classic error:

```
InvalidRequest: Error from server: code=2200 [Invalid query] message="ORDER BY is only supported when the partition key is restricted by an EQ or an IN."
```

Note that I have no intention of clustering by randnumber or ever querying but that column.

Answer (score 2):

In its present state, that table can't support that query.  Without a `WHERE` clause, it's going to default to the order of the hashed token value of the partition keys.  That will *never* be sequential.

Depending on the number of random numbers generated over time, I'd recommend creating a new partition key based on a time component.  So something like `month` or `day` might work.

```
PRIMARY KEY (month, timestamp)
) WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (timestamp DESC);
```

Then this query would work:

```
SELECT * FROM rand_keyspace.rands
WHERE month='202110'
LIMIT 10;
```

With this `PRIMARY KEY` and `CLUSTERING ORDER` definition, you wouldn't need the `ORDER BY` clause, as that would happen by default (in descending order).

I wrote an article about how to solve for this a few years back: [We Shall Have Order!](https://www.datastax.com/blog/we-shall-have-order).  It might help you think through your approach.

Answer (score 1):

To add to Aaron's [fantastic] response, sorting by partition key isn't supported because it requires a full table scan. Cassandra is designed for OLTP workloads where you need to retrieve a single partition really quickly.

You have an analytics use case so instead of plain CQL, you need to use Spark to efficiently scan over multiple partitions. This is a common access pattern for use cases which need to identify what's trending say over the last 5 minutes. Cheers!